# Ember.JS A BEFORE() function for every controller action

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to create some sort of before() function for every action inside a controller?

I know I can do an init() for every action, but what if I have a some code I want to run for every thing? It would be way too redundant to create the same init() function for each action.

Comment: What do you mean by "create the same `init()` function for each action"? I thought you wanted to run the same logic before each action, which mean you'd have to create it only once (and why would you call it `init()`?). Do you mean **call** it from each action? That hardly seems onerous.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to run code before every action without explicitly calling it yourself. At one point there was an idea to lookup actions using `get()`, which would have allowed this, but it never got implemented. Not sure what your use case is, but if you really do need to call functionality before *every* action call, just call it yourself. It'll be much more readable than any clever hacks we could come up with.

Comment: Well I'm new to Ember.js but so far it seems to me that when I go from page to page, the <title> and <meta> tags will never change.
Since Ember.js is essentially a single page app, even though I can save the History states, the tags inside <head> will not change. I can try putting ember code inside the <head> but I feel like ember code should belong in <body> only. Am I wrong in thinking this way? How do most people writing ember code deal with <title> tags?

Comment: I don't think there's a preferred way of dealing with title integration (yet). But if that's your end goal, [this question might be somewhat of a strawman](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would suggest asking a new question with more details about how and when you want to change the title. That will help us get to a solution of your original problem. (Personally, I would use computed properties, but it depends on your use case.)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like this:

First make sure your controller extends the `Ember.TargetActionSupport' mixin.

```
Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport,{
    ...
 });
```

This will allow you to trigger actions programmatically.  See more about this: [Ember.TargetActionSupport](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html)

Then you would make an entry point action that contains your common code and a call to trigger the proper action:

```
Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport,{
    actions: {
        common: function (actionName) {
            //Do common logic here
            this.set('foo', 'bar');

            //And then trigger the intended action
            this.triggerAction({
                action: actionName,
                target: this
            });
        },
        otherAction: function () {
            //Do some more logic here
            this.set('bar', 'baz');
        }
    }
});
```

You would call this action from your template like this:

```
<button {{action 'common' 'otherAction'}}>Press Me</button>
```